# CSS: Style and color external links

Tags: css, url, hyperlink, href, external

I want to style all external links in my website (Xenforo). I'm trying with:

```
a[href ^= "http"]:after {
     content: " " url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAVklEQVR4Xn3PgQkAMQhDUXfqTu7kTtkpd5RA8AInfArtQ2iRXFWT2QedAfttj2FsPIOE1eCOlEuoWWjgzYaB/IkeGOrxXhqB+uA9Bfcm0lAZuh+YIeAD+cAqSz4kCMUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=);    
}
```

Looks good, but i need to add red color too. How can i do that?

Comment: Do you want the link text, or the icon you're adding, to be red?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same attribute select, and style the `a` element with  red color:

```css
a[href ^= "http"] {
  color: red;
}

a[href ^= "http"]::after {
     content: " " url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAVklEQVR4Xn3PgQkAMQhDUXfqTu7kTtkpd5RA8AInfArtQ2iRXFWT2QedAfttj2FsPIOE1eCOlEuoWWjgzYaB/IkeGOrxXhqB+uA9Bfcm0lAZuh+YIeAD+cAqSz4kCMUAAAAASUVORK5CYII=);    
}
```

```html
<a href="/cats">Internal</a>

<a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">Internal</a>
```